# Django - Saving function value to every model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I have this model:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):

    ip = "placeholder"
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=ip)

   

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

and the following function:

```py
    def get_ip_address(request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return ip
    
    ip = get_ip_address(request)
```

What what I need to do to make it so that every time an instance of the model is created, the function runs and saves the returned value in the field called `location`. I assume that I have to put the function in the views.py file but how do I link it to the model instances.

Answer (score 1):

You run it on the view and save it to the instance.

```py
class YourView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        ip = get_ip_address(request)
        profile = Profile(...) # instantiate
        profile.location = ip
        profile.save()
```

Or create the instance directly with the ip on it.

```py
class YourView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        ip = get_ip_address(request)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(..., location=ip) # create and save
```